# Searching for a value inside a graph and printing the value under it

Tags: c

I'm completely new to coding, taking my first course in C-language right now and our assignment is to make a table(graph) of Finland population in 5 different years. This i can do obviously but the problem is that the user has to input a specific year (let's say 1950) and the program will search through the table and tell the population of that year.

The issue i have is that i have no idea how to search through the table.

Here's the code:

```
    int r;
    int s;
    unsigned int pop[2][5] ={1900,1950,2000,2018,2019,2656000,4030000,5181000,5518000,5525000};
    
    for (r=0; r<2;r++)
        {
        for (s=0; s<5;s++)
            printf("%d ",pop[r][s]);
        printf("\n");
}
    printf("\n");
    int year;
    printf("Choose one of the following years: 1900, 1950, 2000, 2018 tai 2019\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    
    if (year = pop[r])
        printf("Population fo the year you chose was: %d\n", pop[s]);
```

didn't include main etc...

thanks for the help!!

Comment: `if (year = pop[r])` are you sure you want to do assignment?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled with a basic set of compilation flags? See your compiler's documentation, e.g. for `gcc`/`clang`, e.g. use options like `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 -g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search from the table, you should check each elements of the table using a loop.

Also note that you should use `==` operator, not `=` operator, for comparision.

```
for (s=0; s<5; s++)
{
    if (year == pos[0][s])
    {
        printf("Population fo the year you chose was: %d\n", pop[1][s]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That helped. It works now as it should and thanks for explaining what i didn't understand! :)